# Microsoft Graph Message search API doesn't work with com

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I was trying to fetch a mail sent by my outlook account to an email (`xyz.abc+5@gmail.com`). Notice that email has `+` in the address

There is a query:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="to:xyz.abc+5@gmail.com"&$select=subject,toRecipients,from&$top=5`

Which returns no messages even though I can see a mail has been sent to this email in my sent folder.

Now if tweak this query a little bit - (remove `com` from email)
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="to:xyz.abc+5@gmail."&$select=subject,toRecipients,from&$top=5`

Strangely, now the response contains the correct message.

This is a very weird issue I came across, can anybody tell me what I'm missing or there is any bug with Graph API?

Comment: Are you URL encoding the string before you send it? It should read `xyz.abc%2B5%40gmail.com`.

Comment: Yes, I'm encoding both the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test and [official docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter), you should better use the search like the following, it will return values:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="to:xyz.abc"&$select=subject,toRecipients,from
```

Although no official docs announced this, but it seems the search will ignore the *.com value, so the the returned result is null.

Comment: Yup, for time being I'm doing that but it doesn't seem right. What if there are two email ids, one with `.com` and one with `.org`?

Comment: To avoid this one(user.com and user.org all exists).  Or we need to research if we can get the other identity to distinguish between them

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Executing `$search="noreply@Planner.Office365.com"&$select=subject,sender` against the Graph Explorer demo data surfaces several results, switching to `.org` (`$search="noreply@Planner.Office365.com"&$select=subject,sender`) returns no records.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I've updated the query. Added `to` field in search

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work for other domain like `students.iiit.ac.in` too

Comment: So it should be better use the mail alias directly. Although we cannot distinguish a user with different domain.

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce this. `$search="to:MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"` returns multiple results, switching to `$search="to:MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.org"` returns none.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur do you have try company account or o365 trail account. It should be easy to reproduce. I have reproduced this in my personal machine and work machine.

Comment: This was using Graph Explorer (using the default tenant/demo data).

Comment: So it should be better test it with some real account(login-in user). Some demo data itself maybe have bug ……

Comment: Something else must be going on here. I'm not seeing this issue in _any_ tenant (demo or not). I'm able to search for `.com` and `.org` and receive the expected results.

Comment: @SeiyaSu, I'm having this issue on real accounts too.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I think you got my question wrong. When I search using "xyz.abc+5@gmail.com" - I get no results, but when I search using "xyz.abc+5@gmail." - I get the expected results.